# Dev Tools app on Android Emulator crashing on sdcard scanning?

Tags: android, android-emulator, devtools

So I open Dev Tools app to refresh emulator's sd card. The sd card has been re-created, is not read-only and I can create folders on it, move files, etc.

And when I click on "Scan SD Card" button

[image]

the app crashes.

[image]

Did anyone have issues like this on the Emulator? Emulator is running SDK 19 (4.4.2), it's x86 image with XXHDPI resolution.

I am running Android Studio 1.0 and AVD was created using Android Studio 0.8 or something.

It's odd that I cannot find similar issues on Internet, like it's happening to me only.

**EDIT**

Logcat Error I get is

```
Process: com.android.development, PID: 2035
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED from pid=2035, uid=10021
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1465)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerNative.java:2373)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast(ContextImpl.java:1127)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast(ContextWrapper.java:365)
        at com.android.development.MediaScannerActivity.startScan(MediaScannerActivity.java:123)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: you are not alone who have this problem

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try running it from the 'ADB Command Prompt'
This command did the trick for me:
`adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED -d file:///mnt/sdcard/DCIM/100ANDRO/`
Now, I can see images uploaded from the Android Device Monitor.